Proof verification about the union of connected spaces being connected.
The question itself is "Suppose $A, B$ are connected subsets of a space $X$ such that
$A \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$. Prove that A U B is connected."
Now this question has been asked in the Exchange but none resemble my attempted proof, which is the following:
Let $A, B$ be conencted subsets of $X$. If $A \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$, then there is some element $x \in X$ belonging to both sets. Since $x \in \overline{B}$, by definition there exists an open subset $U \subseteq X$ such that $x \in U$ and $U \cap B \neq \emptyset$. Because $x \in A$, there are two cases to consider: (1) where $A = U$ and $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, and (2) where $A \neq U$ so $x \in A \cap U$ and $x \in \overline{A} = A$ implying $A$ is closed. Both cases violate the condition of a partition $\{A, B\}$, which is the only possible partition in $A \cap B$ since both sets are connected.
Compared to other proofs for this question, my is quite longer. Therefore, I think I made a mistake somewhere, but I cannot spot it. Any feedback is appreciated!


Since $x \in \overline{B}$, by definition there exists an open subset $U \subseteq X$ such that $x \in U$ and $U \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

This is a concerning step. The closure of $B$ does not grant you such a $U$. It says that, for any open $U$ containing $x$ that you may select, there will be a non-empty intersection $U \cap B$. It doesn't guarantee that such a $U$ exists. What does guarantee such a $U$ exists is the fact that $X$ itself must be open (and $X$ contains $x$ by assumption). So, if this is how you use the closure, then you are wasting the power that the closure gives you.

Because $x \in A$, there are two cases to consider: (1) where $A = U$ and $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, and (2) where $A \neq U$ so $x \in A \cap U$ and $x \in \overline{A} = A$ implying $A$ is closed.

In the second case, where you assume $A \neq U$, I buy that $x \in A \cap U$; we know that $x \in A \cap \overline{B}$, so $x \in A$, and our $U$ contains $x$ by our construction of $U$ (as above). From here, one could conclude that $x \in \overline{A}$, simply because we already know that $x \in A$, and $A \subseteq \overline{A}$ (for any set $A$).
What we can't conclude here is that $A$ is closed. If you wanted to show that $A$ is closed, you'd need to show that, for any $y \in \overline{A}$, we have $y \in A$. You have shown it for $x$, which is not arbitrarily in $\overline{A}$. It is already assumed to be $A$ (making the conclusion that $x \in A$ trivial), plus it is also assumed to be in $\overline{B}$. It is not a general argument, and the conclusion that $A$ is closed is erroneous.
As a concrete counterexample, consider, in $\Bbb{R}$, the sets $A = (0, 1]$ and $ B = (1, 2)$. The intersection $A \cap \overline{B}$ is $(0, 1] \cap [1, 2] = \{1\}$. In this case, the only choice for $x$ is $1$. So, yes, $1$ does belong to $A$ and $\overline{A} = [0, 1]$, but $A$ is definitely not closed.

Both cases violate the condition of a partition $\{A, B\}$, which is the only possible partition in $A \cap B$ since both sets are connected.

There was no assumption that $A$ and $B$ are a partition. They may not be relatively open in $A \cup B$ either. You'd need to assume you have relatively open $V$ and $W$, disjoint, such that $A \cup B = V \cup W$, and show one of them must be empty.

Thank you for the detailed answer! I see that I do not yet fully understand/grasp the implications of certain mathematical concepts, as well as constructing a sound proof. If I understood correctly, I should have started my proof by making an assumption of the existence of a partition, so that my ending conclusion makes sense. However, I did not fully understand the $A \cup B =  V \cup W$ part. Would you mind elaborating? Also, can a proof be made for this particular question that still follows the line of thought I had without going beyond the scope of undergradute topology?

@nico I don't think the proof can be salvaged. Without trying to be discouraging, the proof seems to be fundamentally built on a misunderstanding about the characterisation of the closure (i.e. all open neighbourhoods of $x \in \overline{B}$ must intersect $B$, not just a single one). The confusing of $A$ and $B$ with the partition of open sets also seems to be important. Beyond that, I can't really extract much logic from this approach. I think it's probably unsalvageable.

Regarding the $V$ and $W$, remember that a space is connected if it can be partitioned into two non-empty open sets. That is, a topological space $X$ is disconnected if and only if there are open subsets $V$ and $W$ such that $X = V \cup W$, $V \cap W = \emptyset$, and $V, W \neq \emptyset$. I'm just applying this definition when we consider the (sub)space $X = A \cup B$.

Interesting. Unfortunate that the proof cannot be salvaged, but it makes sense due to a faulty base. With the definition of connectedness "remember that a space is connected if it can be partitioned into two non-empty open sets.", did you mean disconnected? Why was my assumption that the only possible partition of $A \cup B$, given that A and B are connected, is ${A, B}$? Could you give a counterexample of it?

@nico Yes, I do mean disconnected, now that I've had more sleep. As for a counterexample, there isn't one, because there is no disjoint non-trivial open partition of $A \cup B$, as $A \cup B$ is connected. To say $A$ and $B$ are the only possible open sets that could partition $A \cup B$ implies that you have some reasoning that excludes every other possibility. If that is the case, then you should put that reasoning into the proof.
